# Map domain class with predifined values to table

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

Is it possible to create domain class which will be mapped to db table with predefined values, for example:

id    value

1    test1

2    test2

3    test3

Or I have to manualy edit generated *.sql file to acomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are all of your values pre-defined, or only some of them? I.e. will you be creating new instances at runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to have a static set of predefined rows in a table is to populate it in `BootStrap.groovy`.  For example:

```
def init = { servletContext ->
    if (MyDomain.count() == 0) {
        new MyDomain(id: 1, value: 'test1').save(failOnError: true)
        new MyDomain(id: 2, value: 'test2').save(failOnError: true)
        new MyDomain(id: 3, value: 'test3').save(failOnError: true)
    }
}
```

Another approach would be to use the migrations plugin and create a database migration to populate the table.